# Sails - Overriding default routes in routes.js

Tags: sails.js

Wondering why this is not working

```
    // routes.js

          'GET /user/me' : {
            controller : 'user',
            action     : 'me'
          },

          'GET /user/:id' : {
            controller : 'user',
            action     : 'findOne'
          }

    // UserController.js

    module.exports = {
    me: function(req, res, next) {
       // some code here
    },

    findOne: function(req, res, next) {
       // some code here
    };
    }
```

HTTP call to "/user/me" never hits **UserController.me** but always **UserController.findOne**.

**UPDATE**

Problem was with api restPrefix defined in blueprints.js

```
restPrefix: '/api',
```

So my routes should be

```
  'GET /api/user/me': {
    controller: 'user',
    action: 'me'
  },

  'GET /api/user/:id': {
    controller: 'user',
    action: 'findOne'
  }
```

Comment: With a fresh sails.js project + your controller and routes, I get the expected behaviour. Have you relifted sails after the changes?

Comment: OK, found the reason and updated my answer.